# How to find delta within array?

Tags: arrays, delta

I need help. 
I have an array, that will constantly change. Example:

```
var dataset2=[
            [100, 50],
            [150, 200],
            [300, 150]
            ];
```

And I need to find delta within array (d[1]-d[0]), the result should be a new array [-50,50,-150].Thank you beforehand!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please follow to ask instructions. You need to provide first try solving yourself, then ask question here. You need to share what you have tried out and where you are facing issue. This is not free coding service.

Comment: I'm just learning, so I have only primitive solution.     var newdata0=dataset2[0];
            data_delta=newdata[1]-newdata[0];var newdata1=dataset2[1];
            data_delta=newdata[1]-newdata[0];var newdata2=dataset2[2];
            data_delta=newdata[1]-newdata[0];   But this does not fit, as I'll have many arrays(((